# Why are direct close votes and reviews close votes disconnected?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I like how the historic of edited text is handled: a link on the post allows anyone to tell who has done which modification and who approved it if applicable.

On the other side, I have some difficulties to understand how the close vote history is being handled.

It seems that close vote cast using the post's "Close" link is different than the close vote cast through the review queue. Once a vote has been cast through the review queue, pressing the browser's "back" button allows to get the listing of other reviewers (it's such a strange feature I initially contacted StackeExchange support by fear it was a bug...), but this listing does not cover non-review close votes so the number of close votes here does not reflect the actual number of close votes for this post.

Why this difference? Why not merge these two kind of close votes? Or why at least not simply have a page which would list all close votes cast for a post (ideally with a link from the close banner)?

Answer (score 3):

The page you see in review is not a "close vote history", it is the transcript of review actions. You may notice that it sometimes includes other actions: *Leave Open* or *Edit*, not only *Close*.

It makes sense for a transcript of review to reflect what happened in the process of review, and not what happened independently of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the transcript of reviews make sense. However, in this case is there any transcript of the close votes cast on a post? For instance, when I encounter a post recently edited with the "close(3)" indicator showing that there are current close votes, I often wonder if these close votes are old ones from before the post edition and not retracted yet, or if they are new ones because other members of the community feel that the last modifications were not sufficient and the post might therefore require further improvements.

Comment: I also had a strong hope of having solved this when I discovered the posts timeline feature (`/posts/[question-id]/timeline` URL's), however still a bad guess: the close vote do not seem to appear here too :(, however it would be really usefull to see them associated to the post modifications.

Answer (score 1):

According to another Meta.SE question I just found, it seems there is a limitation in the database or the data request interface design which prevents to query such information:

[How to view history of question close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229142/302595)

> There's no query in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) that you
>   could make to find this information.
>
> I guess it's possible that you could visit that question at least once
>   a day and keep track of how many current close votes it has, and
>   compare that from the previous day. But other than that, or some like
>   script to take a screen shot of that page each day, there isn't a
>   simple way to just view this information.